# how to forward subdomain to an external url with paramater value

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I'd like to forward user who use a subdomain to an external URL which has a pattern like 'externaldomain.com/?parameter=x'.

Could I do it on AWS console? If not, what should add in my nginx setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about doing it in the AWS Console, however it can be done with NGINX. First thing you'll want to have is a server block for the subdomain (if you don't already):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://externaldomain.com/?parameter=x
}
```

If you want parameter to contain the domain they visited before, change the return line to this:

```
return 301 $scheme://externaldomain.com/?parameter=$request_uri
```

Comment: Do I need to add a server block for my main domain?

Comment: Not unless you want to use NGINX to serve your main domain